# Why does updating a List<StatefulWidget> that is used in a ListView fail to update the display?

Tags: dart, flutter

I'm trying to create an application to display the results of a search. I have the following extremely simple `StatefulWidget`. It has a single state variable `data`, which is passed in the constructor.

```
class Entry extends StatefulWidget {
  Entry({Key key, @required this.data}) : super(key: key);

  final String data;

  @override
  _EntryState createState() => _EntryState(data);
}

class _EntryState extends State<Entry> {
  _EntryState(this.data) : super();
  final String data;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Text(data);
  }
}
```

To generate datasets of random length (between 0-9) I use the following helper function, which basically keeps track of the `DateTime` and the string that is passed to it:

```
List<String> render(String searchTerm) {
  final Random rng = new Random();
  final String date = DateTime.now().toString();
  return List<String>.generate(
    rng.nextInt(10),
    (int i) => '$searchTerm $i $date',
  );
}
```

Lastly, my main widget is as such. It uses a state variable `_items` to keep track of a list of `Entry`s. One can do a new query through a search bar, which could return a dataset of random length. The list is then displayed through a `ListView`.

```
class MyWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  MyWidget({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  final String title = "Demo";

  @override
  _State createState() => _State();
}

class _State extends State<MyWidget> {
  List<String> _items = [];

  Future<Null> getData(String searchTerm) async {
    final entriesToAdd = render(searchTerm);
    setState(() {
      _items = entriesToAdd;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: TextField(
            onSubmitted: getData,
            decoration:
                InputDecoration(hintText: 'Search', icon: Icon(Icons.search)),
          ),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              Expanded(
                  child: ListView.builder(
                      itemCount: _items.length,
                      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                        return Container(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0), child: Entry(data: _items[index]));
                      })),
            ],
          ),
        ));
  }
}
```

So my issue is that I expect that when I do a search through the button (i.e. call `getData`), the list displayed will be updated with the results of the new query, completely overwriting the old ones. This is not what happens. The displayed list is the correct length, but the items are often a mix of various previous/current searches like the following screenshot, which shows a mix of 2 searches. However, when doing print statements in the `itemBuilder` function of the `ListView`, the `_item` variable seems to be updating correctly, and regardless there shouldn't really be a mix of 2 different search results. What's causing this behavior? [image: bugged]

Here's the full code:

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:math';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/rendering.dart';

void main() => runApp(App());

class App extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.green,
      ),
      initialRoute: '/',
      routes: <String, WidgetBuilder>{
        '/': (BuildContext context) => MyWidget(),
      },
    );
  }
}

class MyWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  MyWidget({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  final String title = "Demo";

  @override
  _State createState() => _State();
}

class _State extends State<MyWidget> {
  List<String> _items = [];

  Future<Null> getData(String searchTerm) async {
    final entriesToAdd = render(searchTerm);
    setState(() {
      _items = entriesToAdd;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: TextField(
            onSubmitted: getData,
            decoration:
                InputDecoration(hintText: 'Search', icon: Icon(Icons.search)),
          ),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              Expanded(
                  child: ListView.builder(
                      itemCount: _items.length,
                      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                        return Container(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0), child: Entry(data: _items[index]));
                      })),
            ],
          ),
        ));
  }
}

class Entry extends StatefulWidget {
  Entry({Key key, @required this.data}) : super(key: key);

  final String data;

  @override
  _EntryState createState() => _EntryState(data);
}

class _EntryState extends State<Entry> {
  _EntryState(this.data) : super();
  final String data;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Text(data);
  }
}


List<String> render(String searchTerm) {
  final Random rng = new Random();
  final String date = DateTime.now().toString();
  return List<String>.generate(
    rng.nextInt(10),
    (int i) => '$searchTerm $i $date',
  );
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't cache Widgets! You should be building them fresh on each call to `build`. (If you are worried about this being inefficient, don't. This is how Flutter is designed and heavily optimized to support this.) Just keep the list of Strings and re-build the Texts each time.

Avoid classes with just static functions. These can be replaced with top-level functions.

Try this instead:

```
import 'dart:math';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/rendering.dart';

void main() => runApp(App());

class App extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.green,
      ),
      initialRoute: '/',
      routes: <String, WidgetBuilder>{
        '/': (BuildContext context) => const MyWidget(),
      },
    );
  }
}

class MyWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyWidget({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  MyWidgetState createState() => MyWidgetState();
}

class MyWidgetState extends State<MyWidget> {
  List<String> _items = <String>[];

  void getData(String searchTerm) {
    final List<String> newEntries = helper(searchTerm);
    setState(() {
      _items = newEntries;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: TextField(
          onSubmitted: getData,
          decoration: const InputDecoration(
            hintText: 'Search',
            icon: Icon(Icons.search),
          ),
        ),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Expanded(
              child: ListView.builder(
                itemCount: _items.length,
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) => Container(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                      child: Text(_items[index]),
                    ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

List<String> helper(String searchTerm) {
  final Random rng = new Random();
  final String date = DateTime.now().toString();
  return List<String>.generate(
    rng.nextInt(10),
    (int i) => '$searchTerm $i $date',
  );
}
```

Here's a version that illustrates using `StatefulWidget`:

```
class MyWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyWidget({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  MyWidgetState createState() => MyWidgetState();
}

class MyWidgetState extends State<MyWidget> {
  List<String> _items = <String>[];

  void getData(String searchTerm) {
    final List<String> newEntries = helper(searchTerm);
    setState(() {
      _items = newEntries;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: TextField(
          onSubmitted: getData,
          decoration: const InputDecoration(
            hintText: 'Search',
            icon: Icon(Icons.search),
          ),
        ),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Expanded(
              child: ListView.builder(
                itemCount: _items.length,
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) => Container(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                      child: Entry(data: _items[index]),
                    ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Entry extends StatefulWidget {
  const Entry({Key key, @required this.data}) : super(key: key);

  final String data;

  @override
  _EntryState createState() => _EntryState();
}

class _EntryState extends State<Entry> {
  bool bold = true;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => GestureDetector(
        onTap: () {
          setState(() {
            bold = !bold;
          });
        },
        child: Text(
          widget.data,
          style: TextStyle(
            fontWeight: bold ? FontWeight.bold : FontWeight.normal,
          ),
        ),
      );
}
```

Comment: I'm not trying to cache the Widgets actually. The `class Entry` could have as their state variable as a `String` and the same issue would happen if we create a `Text` widget in the build function in `class Entry`. The reason I need the StatefulWidget `class Entry` is because I need to keep track of some internal state inside it, which doesn't affect the result of this question at all.

Comment: It's best to maintain any persistent state (like Favorited, starred) in your application state. Any state that you maintain down in `Entry` should be temporary, for example to do with an animation or text entry, which can be re-created

Comment: Widgets do not have a `state` property. `State`s do have a `widget` property though. You can (kind of) keep a reference to the State by assigning a `Key` to its widget, but if you can you should just keep the data itself, as this answer shows.

Comment: One Flutter-y state management solution (if the size/complexity of your app calls for it): [InheritedModel](https://gist.github.com/HansMuller/b947e76c34d941397989eaab537d45ca)

Comment: @RichardHeap The only solution that's being espoused here is not to use a `StatefulWidget` and that doesn't seem to be a viable solution to me. The choice to make `_items` a `List<String>` vs. a `List<Widget>` makes no difference in the end result really. For example if I want to use a `GestureDetector` to allow each individual entry to have a separate gesture indicator, the documentation from https://flutter.io/tutorials/interactive/ suggests that that's required.

Comment: But as the link you added says "If in doubt, start by managing state in the parent widget.", which is what we've suggested. We haven't said that you shouldn't have a `ListView` of stateful widgets, just that you should recreate all those stateful widgets on the fly in `build` rather than try to cache them.

Comment: @RichardHeap I've edited my question, but if you look at the latest code I have, I do recreate the stateful widgets on the fly in the `itemBuilder` from a `List<String>` and yet this issue still persists.

Comment: Please check the updated answer with `StatefulWidget`. I don't see any issue with this either.

Comment: @RichardHeap Okay, that was helpful. I figured out the issue was trying to pass in the `String data` into the constructor of the `_EntryState`. Thanks